# Is it possible to set the coordinates of the elements to scroll?

Tags: java, selenium

I use a method to scroll into some elements on the page.

```
protected static void scrollIntoView(WebElement element) {
        Main.s_driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    }
```

But for some reason, some elements scrolls to their top, some to their bottom. And because of it I get exceptions.
[See the image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uNZ7.jpg)
I want it always (or at least to control it) to be like on the left picture. Is it available to set coordinates (top) which to scroll to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your usual scroll method as you use plus always add some extra pixels to make element at least clickable.

```
driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, -10);"); // scroll 10px higher
```

Not much convenient, but worked for me.

If you need your element to be whole visible, make this method more specific, like:

```
protected static void scrollIntoView(WebElement element, int pixelsToAddVer) {
        driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
        driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, " + pixelsToAddVer + ");");
    }
```

Unfortunately, you anyway need to count pixels.

Comment: I tried to use driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, -100);"); to move the page down but it didn't work.

Comment: @Maybellene sorry, my mistake. I edited the post. To scroll down you need to use positive numbers, to scroll up - negative.